# Number Spinner with multiple incremental buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

so im pretty newbie into this i searched over the net couldent find any examples anywhere, so im hoping to get some help here if possible

I want to do a number spinner incremental.. so far so good i found some god and i can easily have a left right button that substracts or adds 1, but how do add a couple more buttons next to it that for example substract 10 or adds 10 ?

```
<div id="field1">field 1
    <button type="button" id="sub10" class="sub10">-10</button>
    <button type="button" id="sub1" class="sub1">-1</button>
    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
    <button type="button" id="add1" class="add1">+1</button>
    <button type="button" id="add10" class="add10">+10</button>
</div>
```

```
button {
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input {
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: salmon;
}
```

```
$('.add1').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
});
$('.sub1').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().val() > 0) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
});
$('.add10').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 10);
});
$('.sub10').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().val() > 0) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 10);
});
```

The -1, +2 buttons work fine.. i want to make it work so that when i press -10 or +10 to work also.. 
Here is a fiddle to where i am stuck at:
http://jsfiddle.net/5mvutyb6/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `next()` and `prev()` to get the `<input/>` element. That only works when the pressed buttons is immediately above or below the input.

To fix that, just get the input by its ID.

Here is an example:

```js
var $input = $('#1');
$('.add1').click(function () {
    $input.val(+$input.val() + 1);
});
$('.sub1').click(function () {
    if ($input.val() > 0) $input.val(+$input.val() - 1);
});
$('.add10').click(function () {
    $input.val(+$input.val() + 10);
});
$('.sub10').click(function () {
    if ($input.val() > 0) $input.val(+$input.val() - 10);
});
```

```css
button {
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input {
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="field1">field 1
    <button type="button" id="sub10" class="sub10">-10</button>
    <button type="button" id="sub1" class="sub1">-1</button>
    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
    <button type="button" id="add1" class="add1">+1</button>
    <button type="button" id="add10" class="add10">+10</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that !

Comment: @sKoop I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Like Titus already said, the `prev()` and `next()` functions were the problems.

Additionally I would use some helper functions to reduce the complexity and get a better understanding for whats going on. It's always a good idea to cache your variables. Another point are the possible negative values. In your code sample the input value will be checked for > 0 but if your value is 1 and you press the "-10" button you will get -9.

You can prevent it with this line:

```
if (v <= 0) { v = 0; }
```

Here the full sample:

```js
var $input = $('#1');

var plus = function( value ) {
  $input.val( parseInt( $input.val() ) + value );
}

var minus = function( value ) {
  var v = parseInt( $input.val() ) - value;

  if (v <= 0) { v = 0; }
  
  $input.val( v );
}

$('.add1').click( function () { plus( 1 ) });
$('.add10').click( function () { plus( 10 ); } );
$('.sub1').click( function () { minus( 1 ); } );
$('.sub10').click( function () { minus( 10 ); });
```

```css
button {
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input {
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="field1">field 1
    <button type="button" id="sub10" class="sub10">-10</button>
    <button type="button" id="sub1" class="sub1">-1</button>
    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
    <button type="button" id="add1" class="add1">+1</button>
    <button type="button" id="add10" class="add10">+10</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Working perfectly. Would it be complicated to provide a +0.10 and -0.10 value also ? I tried adding them but seems it doesnt work with the decimals

Comment: No it's not. Then you must use the parseFloat function instead of the parseInt and then round the values, to get a pretty output. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n0az5d7v/2/. hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you once again. Really appreciate your help